# How to tell Django 1.5 which url to redirect when the user enters an incorrect password

Tags: django, authentication, redirect

in my Django 1.5 view I used:

```
@login_required(login_url='/my_url/login')
```

All is ok, and redirect well, but if I used a bad login, Django redirect to '/acounts/login' with message.

How can I redirect to '/my_url/login' if user used bad login?

EDIT:

I used standard login views

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
url(r'^login/$', login,{'template_name':'my_url/login.html'}),
```

EDIT 2: my_url/login.html

```html
<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
<div >
<div id="login-box">
<H2>Connectez vous, ou créez un compte</H2>
<br />
<br />
<table align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
<td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
<td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br />

<br />
<br />
<div><input value="login" type="submit"><input name="next" value="{{next}}" type="hidden"></div>
    
</div></div></form>
```

Comment: You mean when the user enters an incorrect password? Please edit the question to add your login view.

Comment: Yes, when the user enters an incorrect password, i used : url(r'^login/$', login,{'template_name':'my_url/login.html'}), and standard from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

Comment: Please update your question and add `my_url/login.html`